# Why does Dapper's .Execute(...) return an int?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

Anyone know why Dapper returns an int from `.Execute(...)` ?

I can't find this documented anywhere.

Comment: Everything aside: this sounds a design question to me. Have you _ever_ ask this on it's github page? Or project creaters? AFAIK, [Marc Gravell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) is one of the co-author. You can ping him on chat or twitter etc..

Comment: Or, being open source, you could simply browse the source and figure out what is being returned.

Comment: Not a design question just wanted to know what the integer is. I'm not going to open an issue on GH for that. Why bother the developers with such trivia?

Comment: And thanks for the helpful suggestion @ron beyer but I asked in hope that someone else would know and therefore I would save time. If everyone worked everything out for themselves you would have no questions to answer for the precious internet points would you?

Comment: Being that as it is, I'd still do a *little* research before just posting the question. Dapper is a single C# file, its very easy to find out why something works the way it does.

Comment: I did a *little* research. I checked the project documentation & checked for existence of a similar question. I started browsing through the source code on GH and after a couple of minutes thought.... hell why not ask on SO. An added benefit to this is that now no one else has to do the same :)

Comment: For all the flak the OP has gotten about a "lack" of research, this question is the top result when I google "dapper execute return value".  Seems like it needed to be asked...

Comment: I agree, we shouldn't have to go digging through source code for the information on what a return value means. This should be detailed on the readme at https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper. This is a valuable question that saves other people having to dig into the source code.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The integer represents the number of rows that were affected by your query.

It returns an integer so you know if your query has worked. If zero is returned and you expected something to have changed then you know there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks!
@RahulTripathi this answers both for me :)

Comment: But 0 may be OK.  For example, let's say you are updating a record, but before you execute, it's deleted out from under you (and let's say that's OK).  I'd like a little more details about this return code.  Will it return 0 for when the record isn't there (like my example) and if there was some type of failure (which I would probably want to act on in a different way)?  Or is failure always going to result in an exception?

Comment: @JustLooking A record not existing isn't a failure. So you will just get a zero response.

Comment: @CathalMF -- I agree.  Maybe I wasn't clear, my bad.  What I'm saying is that I think the record not found should return 0.  But are there instances outside of record not found that will also return 0?  For example, some type of failure.  Or instead, will all failures be an exception.  Thus, it returns 0 for not found, 1 (or more) for actual records affected, exception for failure.

Comment: Or someone at least point me to good dapper documentation.  Take a look at microsoft.  As an example, I'm looking at DataAdapter Update documentation.  It says it returns an Int32 (rows updated) and then it lists the exceptions it throws.  Perfect!  Where's the Dapper equivalent?

Comment: Yes actual failures will result in an exception. Dapper is open source. Look at the code on GitHub to see what it does.

Answer (score 21):

Because [DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) (which Dapper uses internally, no doubt) returns an int for the number of rows affected. Why? Because it's more or less free, and is about the only thing that you can reasonably return for a generic INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: This should have given it away!